# React useEffect fetch hook makes endless calls despite array parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, infinite-loop, use-effect

My code is meant to render a new list whenever the **task** state changes. In terms of what the function is meant to do, it works--displaying my list of tasks upon state change. However, it runs endlessly even before state change, causing the computer to overheat.

If I use an empty array instead, the infinite calls stop, but I have to refresh the page for changes to register. Here's the code:

in Context.jsx:

```
const [task, setTask] = React.useState([ 
        {
        title: "",
      },]);
```

in InputTask.jsx: a button triggers handleClick. This is how tasks are added to my backend.

```
function handleClick(e) {
    const newTask = {
      title: input,
    };
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001", newTask);
    console.log(task);
    setInput("");
  }
```

in Task.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then((jsonRes) => setTask(jsonRes))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [task]); 

  return (
    <ul>
      {task.map((task, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="task" key={index}>
            <button className="task-button" onClick={() => handleDelete(task._id)}></button>
              <h3>{task.title}</h3>            
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ul> 
  );
```

Comment: Objects are compared by reference, not by their keys and values, so each time you call `setTask` even if they are "the same", `task` will contain a new object reference and the `useEffect` will re-run. So the infinite loop is expected here.

Comment: You mentioned a "list" in your question, are you intending to update the state/value of some sort of list of data stored with `useState` when task changes? Currently you aren't updating this "list" in any way in the `useEffect`.

Comment: My next question is why is `task` a dependency anyway? I don't understand the underlying logic for wanting this? (anytime `task` changes, change `task`?)

Comment: @BrianThompson I suspect the OP may be following the advice of a linter without understanding the actual underlying mechanics. If you remove task ESLint with settings provided by say, create-react-app will warn that you're missing a dependency in the array.

Comment: @BrianThompson yeah task is an array of objects actually and I want it to display change when it changes. Maybe as you say I need to change the reference, not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a post request return the updated tasks in response and update it at the same instant.

```js
async function handleClick(e) {
    const newTask = {
      title: input,
    };
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001", newTask);
    if(res.data.task){
      setTask(res.data.task); // your res should have task
    }
    setInput("");
}
```

No need to use useEffect for updating the task list on the front-end.